# Where to find the sighash type?

Tags: script, sighash

Where can I find the sighash type specified in a script?
Is it included in the scriptsig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's generally part of the `scriptSig`.

More specifically, it's part of the signature pushed by the script.

Most specifically, it's the last byte of the signature.